# Is AFIncrementalStore still being maintained?

Tags: objective-c, afincrementalstore

I noticed that it's been almost a year since the last commit to AFIncrementalStore, is that project still relevant or being maintained?

https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore

Are there other alternatives to AFIncrementalStore in the API object mapping / REST / ORM category?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not anymore, it's officially discontinued :( https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFIncrementalStore